# K8S Read config map via go API

Tags: go, kubernetes

I’ve a config map which I need to read from K8S via api

I Created a cluster role

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: zrole
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["configmaps"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
```

and cluster role binding

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: z-role-binding
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: system:serviceaccounts
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: zrole
```

Config Map

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: z-config
  namespace: fdrs
data:
  avr: client1
  fuss: xurbz
```

The [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/kubernetes/typed/core/v1/configmap.go) is used like

clientSet.CoreV1().ConfigMaps(uNamespcae)

when I run the code locally (and provide to the the GO api the kubeconfig) I was able to get the config map data,
However when I run the code inside the cluster I got error: `invalid token` , any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you attached a service account to the pod?

Comment: @zerkms - it runs from local without service-account, is this a must to use machinary permmission in this case? if yes please provide it as answer and i’ll close the question . thanks

Comment: I think it is related to kubeconfig not being set properly. Do you set KUBECONFIG environment variable?

Comment: @Jonlib "it runs from local without service-account" --- that's a weak argument. To interact with API you need a valid token. If you have created a `zrole` role - you must create a service account and attach it to a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [`automountServiceAccountToken`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#pod-v1-core) in the pod spec. By default it's set to `true`, but maybe you have it disabled.

Use the official GO client. It reads the correct configuration and tokens by default. https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/in-cluster-client-configuration/main.go

If you don't use it, then use the correct configuration:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/#directly-accessing-the-rest-api-1

Check the token in the pod: `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` and use the `kubernetes` service.

Comment: Thanks! you write to check the `automountServiceAccountToken` and the path to the token , could you please write how to do it from the cli ?

Comment: By checking `automountServiceAccountToken` I mean to check your yaml files. Just look for it. If you can not find it, most likely it is enabled. The token could be checked very easily. Just "exec" into the pod and see if the files are there: `kubectl exec -it <pod-name> sh`. Then `ls /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`.